# Do I have to change security rules in firebase if I'm not using database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

If I were to build a site without database interaction (no login on the site) with firebase. Do I need to change default security rules that looks like this:

```
 {
        "rules": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": true
        }

 }
```

This red exclamation sign in the security & rules section says that I better write some security rules. So the question is, is it safe to leave this as is if you don't use login/signup ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The thing is, FireBase has changed a lot. The new admin area has predefined security measures in place. So, you don't really have to worry about that anymore.

The default set of rules are

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

And in case you want to open them up for both read and write permissions, you can roll back to

```
{
   "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the default rule:

```
 "rules": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": true
        }
```

everybody can read and can write your data using the Android,IOS and WEB SDKs.

You should provide a kind of authentication with a Token or with Email/Password authentication.

```
 "rules": {
         ".read": "auth !== null",
         ".write": "auth !== null",       
       }
```

Pay attention because your **rules don't effect** what you can or can't do in the **Firebase dashboard**. Anyone with access to the dashboard, including collaborators who you share your Firebase dashboard with, can circumvent the rules.

More info [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/understanding-security.html).

Comment: But if I write these "auth !== null" rules, will I still be able to deploy changes to my site, right ?  And another question is if I have just default rules then anyone can just change my site bypassing "firebase login" ? I mean, when I try in the first time to access to my firebase it ask me to do "firebase login". I just don't understand what "everybody can read and can write your data." means, does anybody can access my site without doing the authentication "firebase login" if I leave the default rules? 

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Un1 Don't confuse the access with the web gui and the access with the code. Your site can access the data without any authentication (it is not related with your login in the web page). It means that everyone can build a site that access the same firebase url....

Comment: Okay, so if I just make .read and .write "auth !== null" then the only person that will be able to modify my site is me, right ? I'm sorry for silly newbie questions.

Comment: This rules means that only authenticated users can read and write the data in your firebase url. Check this link: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/understanding-security.html

Answer (score 2):

The security rules in the "Security & Rules" tab of your Firebase dashboard only affect who can access the database.

It has no effect on:

- who can access a web site you host on Firebase. Anyone with the URL can do that.
- who can deploy a web site you host on Firebase. Only the owner and collaborators you invite to your Firebase back-end can do that.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So adding "auth !== null" to .write and .read will have no difference, because I have no database anyway, right ? Can I just leave it as true for both write and read then ?

Comment: Since the security rules in the "Security & Rules" tab of your Firebase dashboard only affect who can access the database, it only matters what you put in there if you use the database.